# "For" loop structure in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As I was debugging a small bit of code, I noticed something unexpected:

The for loop that cycles through the filename to remove the numbers, by looking at each character of the string and replacing it, seems to take a print of the filename as it exists in the first pass of the loop and cycles through those letters, so that if, as I do in the code, make changes to the string passed to the loop, python still looks for those letters that were in the string to begin with.

Have I just uncovered (for myself) a fundamental feature of the for loop, or is this just something weird that resulted from my code?

```
short_list = ['1787cairo.jpg', '237398rochester.jpg']
print short_list
for entry in short_list:
    entry_pos = short_list.index(entry)
    for char in entry:
        print entry, char, ord(char)
        if ord(char) in range (48,58):
            entry = entry.replace(char,'')
        print entry
    short_list[entry_pos] = entry              
print short_list
```

Comment: "... just something weird that resulted from my code" should be way, way down the list of the things that you consider in any given situation.

Comment: If an answer helped you, you should accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point here is that Python variables are really just names that point at objects. When you do `for char in entry` the for loop is iterating over whatever `entry` happens to point to; if you then reassign `entry` to point to something else, the iterator won't know that.

Note that if `entry` happened to be a mutable object, like a list, and you mutated the items in that object, the values seen by the iterator *would* change; again, this is because the iterator is pointing to the object itself.

Really though your code is over-complicated; rather than keeping indexes and replacing items in the list, you should be building up new lists with the changed items:

```
new_list = []
for entry in short_list:
    new_entry = ''
    for char in entry:
        if ord(char) not in range (48,58):
            new_entry += char
    new_list.append(new_entry)
```

and this can be shortened further to a nested list comprehension:

```
[''.join(char for char in entry if ord(char) not in range (48,58)) for entry in short_list]
```

(and, as a further improvement, your check of `ord(char)` can be replaced by `char.isdigit()`.)

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but let me try to re-phrase through my understanding:  The for loop looks at whatever the variable "entry" points to, at that point in time of the code execution, and because it is a string, and this is immutable, the reassignment of "entry" that comes later is not recognized by the iterator, which is still looking at the object pointed to by "entry" originally?  -However, if loop had been executed against a list, i.e. if "entry" was a list, which is mutable, rather than a string, which is not, the iterator would recognize the mutated list it was executing against?

Comment: Hmm, almost. The distinction is not really between mutable and immutable objects, but between mutating and reassigning. If `entry` was a list, but you reassigned it inside the for loop just as you are doing with the string, it would have the same result; but lists *also* have the ability to be mutated without reassigning, and if you did that, then the loop would see the new items. Hope that's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

```
from string import digits

def remove_chars(s, bad_chars):
    """
    Return `s` with any chars in `bad_chars` removed
    """
    bad_chars = set(bad_chars)
    return "".join(ch for ch in s if ch not in bad_chars)

short_list = ['1787cairo.jpg', '237398rochester.jpg']
short_list = [remove_chars(entry, digits) for entry in short_list]
```

which gives

```
['cairo.jpg', 'rochester.jpg']
```